# LightSwitch Users and Roles management option is not appear

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

After deploy my LightSwitch HTMLClient application with forms authentication and Add desktop client in order to manage users and roles, I go to http://mylssite.net/app/desktopclient and then, when I loggin to the administrator site only reset my password appear as option, I don't see any option about users and roles management. I can't add new users to site.

I see this screen:
[image]

What is wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been crazy for a few hours I found the solution to misterius issue. All documentation that I read I see the users and roles tabs in Desktop client appear automatically but not, not isn't. In order to see users or roles tab I click on "ADMINISTRATION" tab on screen and then drop down menu is show with this two options...
[image]

No comment :)

Comment: If you edit the screen navigation(right-click the screens folder of the desktop client), you can specify a screen to be the home screen for the desktop client. Setting it won't affect the HTML client.

Answer (score 0):

another problem I had with this personally was that the "SecurityAdministration" permission was not ticked for "Granted For Debug"... by ticking this is solved my issue with the options not displaying